# Domino 9.01 Fix 3 CKEditor error - No error on 9.01 Fix 1

Tags: ckeditor, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

Hope someone can help me, I've been stuck for a few days now.

After updating my Domino server to 9.01 Fix 3 I keep getting an error on the javascript console:

> TypeError: this.editor.getData is not a function

This is the image of the error:

[Console Error Message](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dq5uvspt041sm6n/Capture.PNG?dl=0)

And all buttons on my page stop working.

If I comment the Richtext code on the page, everything starts working again, this is the code:

```
<xp:inputRichText id="ds_decisao" styleClass="data" disableClientSideValidation="true" value="#{dts_proposta.ds_texto}" required="false" disableValidators="true" title="titulo" immediate="true"></xp:inputRichText>
```

This server is for test purposes, so we have the same code in another one that the version is 9.01 Fix 1, and the error does not happen there. The page code is exactly the same, just the server version is different.

I don't know where in the code the problem is, inside CKEditor or Domino, because both of them get updates going from Fix 1 to Fix 3.

I have tried downgrading the version of CKEditor to the same one that is on the 9.01 Fix 1 server, but the error persists. So maybe that points to something on the Domino code, not the CKEditor, but I don't know.

I have to use Fix 3 for security reasons, and I do need CKEditor.

Has anyone encounter this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does CKEditor show up? Have you tried clearing your browser cache? FP1 uses CKEditor 3.6.x while FP3 uses CKEditor 4.4.x

Comment: I am getting mixed results when testing with Domino server and Notes/Designer both at FP3.  For server and XPiNC the CKEditor does render fine with no errors.  For local web preview the CKEditor does not render and i get two errors ...  1.  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
DemoXPage311.xsp:209 ... and 2. Uncaught [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "lotusspellchecker" was not found at "http://localhost/xsp/.ibmxspres/domino/ckeditor/plugins/lotusspellchecker/plugin.js?t=E7PD".

Comment: CKEditor does show up, and seem to work ok, but I get the error on the console and screws up all javascript code on the page, so my save button don't work, the erase button don't work. The whole page does not respond to any javascript commands. I've tried both CKEditor 3.6.x and CKEditor 4.4.x with the FP3, and I get the same error.

Comment: Per Henrik, I've tried rebooting my PC, clearing the browser cache, rebooting the Domino server. The error persists.

Comment: Is this in the Notes Client or in any web browser? And is the issue showing up for just web preview, or when hitting the full server address?

Comment: Web browser, tried IE, FF and Chrome.

Comment: I've never tried on web preview, always hitting the full server address.

Comment: @Brian, seen my comment above for my testing results.  Fine on XPiNC and server, only errors and will not render for local web preview.

Comment: @Paul that sounds like a separate issue to what cdonate is experiencing

Comment: @Brian, yes different, but may be related?

Comment: I am having the same problem as Paul Della-Nebbia. local preview problems Uncaught [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "lotusspellchecker" was not found at ,and also get Cannot read property 'icons' of null. works fine on server with same version. 9.0.1 FP3

Comment: I'm getting the error in XPiNC, but not in the browser.

Comment: This is still a problem in 9.0.1 FP3 SHF227 (IF3) when running local.

Comment: @cdonate did you ever find a fix for this? I'm experiencing something similar on FP4.

Comment: I also am having the exact same problem, but on only one person, about 30 others it works fine for. Very very strong.

Comment: Same problem here and Declan's comment was right on for me.  Now just need to work around this.

Answer (score 6):

I have recently run in to exactly this issue and exact error message with CKEditor in XPages 9.0.1 FP3

I found that when there is an SSJS onClientLoad event on the page it causes an AJAX POST event to the server and this is stopping the CKEditor from loading successfully. Removing the SSJS onClientLoad event allowed the page to load as expected.

Comment: I wish I had read your answer before this week. Feel free to collect a "community currency token" from me when next we meet Declan. Thanks!